# Banach algebra norms on $M_n(A)$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra (not sure whether I need $A$ to be unital). I saw the claim that all Banach algebra norms on $M_n(A)$ with continuous projections on entries are equivalent. How does one prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is that the map $X\to X_{kj}$ is continuous for each $k,j$. This means that there exists a constant $c$ such that $\|X_{kj}\|\leq c\|X\|$ for all $X\in M_n(A)$. Consider, on $M_n(A)$, the norm
$$
\|X\|_1=\sum_{k,j}\|X_{kj}\|.
$$
Note that $(M_n(A),\|\cdot\|_1)$ is a Banach space. 
The above shows that $\|X\|_1\leq cn^2\|X\|$, so the identity map is continuous $(M_n(A),\|\cdot\|)\to(M_n(A),\|\cdot\|_1)$. As it is bijective, the Open Mapping Theorem guarantees that there is a constant $d$ with $\|X\|\leq d\,\|X\|_1$ for all $X\in M_n(A)$.

Comment: They might have meant starting with a given norm on $A$. Will it then be true?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Take a look at the new argument.